# rec and play video with delay on ipad

Tags: ipad, video, delay, playback

I am french and little newbbie. I have a question :
I want to make a very simple app on ipad : rec video from the ipad and display it with a delay of 15-30 seconds. no record, just display with a delay.
It's for studients (I am teacher).
They will do something (about 30 seconds) in front of the camera and then just have a look about what they did. Excuse for my english... Thanks a lot for your answers...

Answer (score 0):

There's an app that does just that. Live Video Delay on the App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/live-video-delay/id525582638?ls=1&mt=8